# Redirecionar arquivo para URL via .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url

Eu estou usando o UOL Host para meu site e estou tendo problemas para o redirecionamento da página inicial para um subdomínio que criei.
Pesquisando como fazer isso, encontrei que a forma para isso seria:

**Redirect 301 /index.php http://subdominio.meudominio.com.br**

O meu *index.php* tem outro nome. E o link do site é nesse estilo, porém são outras palavras.

Eu coloquei o .htaccess no mesmo diretório que o index.php, mas não funciona quando acesso o link. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

RewriteRule  (.*)  http://site.example.com/%1  [R=301,L]

Extraído de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497233/htaccess-rewriterule-for-subdomain

Comment: Eu acho que apenas a linha _RewriteRule (.*) http://site.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]_ não funciona. Eu tentei o que está nesse link que você mandou, mas não funcionou. O meu caso é um pouco diferente do caso do outro cara. Eu tentei isso:
**RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   ^(www\.)?meusite.com.br/nome_pasta_contem_php_inicial/(.*)
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://subdominio.meusite.com.br/%1  [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ /nome_pasta_contem_php_inicial/php_inicial.php/?var=$1 [L]**
Porém, estou seguindo o exemplo do cara do link. Eu não uso esse var=$1

Answer (score 0):

Vê se isso funciona:

```
redirect 301 http//dominio.com http://subdominio.dominio.com
```